# Swipable tab is not swiping in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to create a navigation drawer with swipe tab. But my viewpager is not working fine.  I can only select the tab. Viewpager can not load any fragment. so I can not swipe it. If i change the height of the viewpager it hides the tab and load all the fragment.

```
Activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">
<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />



<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tab"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.usaukglu.tablayoyt.NavigationDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java Code:

```
package com.example.usaukglu.tablayoyt;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
NavigationDrawer navigationDrawer;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    TabLayout tabLayout= (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tab);
    toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    drawerLayout= (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new   ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),MainActivity.this));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    navigationDrawer= (NavigationDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_drawer);
    navigationDrawer.setUp(R.id.nav_drawer,drawerLayout,toolbar);

}

}
```

Here is my ViewpagerAdapter.java code

```
package com.example.usaukglu.tablayoyt;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
private Context context;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment=null;
    if (position==0){
        fragment=new FragmentPage();
    }
    if (position==1){
        fragment=new FragmentExpense();
    }
    if (position==2){
        fragment=new FragmentIncome();
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    return tabTitles[position];

}
}
```

Comment: FragmentPage, FragmentExpense and FragmentIncome all these are setted with their xml views?

Comment: yes all these are setted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use FrameLayout as container for the tab + pager. FrameLayout is used mostly to put views above others. To fix it you should change this FrameLayout to LinearLayout with vertical  orientation. Also the view page height should be match_parent.